# A question on second symmetric derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose  function $f:J→R$ on an open interval $J$ satisfies following  inequality: 
$$\left|f(x)+f(y)−2f\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\right|\leq C(f)\, |x−y|^{1+\delta}$$ for all $x,y∈J$, and for some  $\delta \in (0,1].$

Is follow from this fact that $f\in C^{1}$ or  $C^{1+\delta}$?

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but what is $C(f)$?

Comment: $C(f)$ is the universal constant i.e. it  depends on $f$ but does not depend on choice of $x$ and $y$